# Wordpress set_transient function hampring my server preformance

Tags: database, performance, wordpress

I am storing site visitor history using wordpress builtin function set_transient.

Whenever visitor
 navigate throughtout the site I am storing history in database using wordpress set_transient function and when any visitor submit contact us form I transfer the history to  parmenent table as the transient data is flushed after 24 hours

But this causing overhead on my wordpress database and eventually it's hampring my server performance can any one help me?

Does any one have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are only using the transient data in the cases where the user sends a contact form (?).

If that is the case, what about storing the navigation history in a session array? If the user submits the contact form, you dump the session array to DB, otherwise, it just will be removed by the garbage collector after the session is terminated.

This way you get rid of that (supposedly) big and unused transient table and all the inserts into it.

Comment: Let me break it for you
1.I store history data on each navigation click in database using set_transient.
2.I generated contact form using Wufoo. In Wufoo form i created extra hidden field and while inseriting the script of wufoo form I have assigned shortcode to that hidden field which generat unique id for each visitor.
3.Using that unique id i store transient data.
4.Once the form is generated i can not access the form elements using javascript or jQuery.
5.So when somebody submits the contact form by using wufoo's feature of webhook I again sent post data to my site.

Comment: 6.At init hook i get the data sent from webhook by using unique id again i get history data using get_transient and insert it in another permanent table.
So i have to use wufoo form. Please help me.